# Trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu with UNetbootin

Tags: dual-boot

So I used UNetbootin to install a Live Ubuntu 16.04 on my hard disk.
When booting up it keeps saying this:
`/dev/sr0:- no medium found`
It also says:
`unable to find a medium containing a live file system`
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: try with different program like rufus, balena etcher or Win32DiskImager and check again if the issue is still there...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/q/16042/)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/921722/